# Can I output timestamps in heroku review app build logs?

Tags: heroku, heroku-review-app

Currently build steps are not output to heroku log aggregates, and as such don't have timestamps. When wanting to debug slow build times, it would be very helpful to enable timestamps at various steps of our build, specifically on the container runtime. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the logs easily in the `Heroku` dashboard with the `timestamps` respectively.

Follow these steps:

- Login to your `Heroku` account.
- Click on the app you want to see the logs.
- In the right top corner click on the `more` option.
- After clicking on more you will see the first option as `view logs`.
- Click on `view logs`

After this, you will able to see your app logs with timestamps.

You can also use an add-on service on your apps.
Check here: https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging

Comment: This appears to only work for application logs, not build logs like the question asked about.